# Oracle retrieving wrong data in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

I have a table in an Oracle database and I passing one `u_id` parameter from my C# app to an Oracle stored procedure to retrieve data based on the `u_id`, but if is pass `u_id` value directly into my stored procedure and run it then it is retrieving the correct data, but whenever I pass an `u_id` value from my C# app and bind that data to a grid, then it is showing all the records from the table, you can check it in a screenshot below:

It is retrieving correct data in Oracle query:

[Oracle query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2uOL.png)

but it is showing all the records on the page:

[wrong data on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPTml.png)

Oracle stored procedure:

```
create or replace procedure uspGetTrackByUID(u_id in varchar2,
                                         p_out out sys_refcursor) as
begin
    open p_out for
        select *
        from tblEmailTrack t
        where t.flag = 'R'
        and t.u_id = u_id;
end;
```

C# code:

```
private void OGetTrackByUID(string uid)
{
        connection();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("uspGetTrackByUID", ocon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("u_id", uid.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_out", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        try
        {
            ocon.Open();
            grdTrack.EmptyDataText = "User haven't read the mail yet";
            grdTrack.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            grdTrack.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            ocon.Close();
            ocon.Dispose();
        }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Change parameter name `u_id` to `i_u_id`. It does not work in your query. `where u_id = t.u_id` is like `where t.u_id = t.u_id`, always true.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607891/pl-sql-stored-procedure-parameter-name-same-as-column-name

Comment: @PonderStibbons Thanks, it worked.